# Union-Find in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, union-find

A few days ago I start learning C++. This code is a simple [Union-Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure.

**Questions:**

- Why can't I use `const union_find<T> &uf` instead of `union_find<T> &uf`?
- Is it possible to replace `union_find<T>` with something like `self<T>` (`self` refers to current class)?
- Did I use references instead of pointers in the right places?

**union_find.cpp:**

```
template<class T>
class union_find {
public:
  union_find(const T &obj) {
    _parent = this;
    _obj = obj;
  }

  void merge(union_find<T> &uf) {
    _parent = &uf;
  }

  T find() {
    union_find<T> *root = _parent;

    while (root != root->_parent) {
      root = root->_parent;
    }

    return root->_obj;
  }
private:
  T _obj;
  union_find<T> *_parent;
};
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "union_find.cpp"

int main() {
  union_find<std::string> foo("foo");
  union_find<std::string> bar("bar");
  union_find<std::string> baz("baz");
  bar.merge(foo);

  std::cout << foo.find() << std::endl; // foo
  std::cout << bar.find() << std::endl; // foo
  std::cout << baz.find() << std::endl; // baz

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Code Review.

1. `union_find.cpp` looks like a header-only library. It's thus strange its not named like a header.
2. Make all single-argument-constructors `explicit` unless you really want to see them used for implicit conversion.
   In our case, you really don't.
3. `class union_find` should be un-copyable, un-movable and not assignable.

   ```
   union_find(union_find&&) = delete;
   union_find(const union_find&) = delete;
   void operator=(union_find&&) = delete;
   void operator=(const union_find&) = delete;
   ```
4. Consider implementing path-compression in `find()`. See your reference.
5. Consider returning a reference from `find()`. No need to make the choice on copying for the caller.
6. If you call `merge()` on a non-root-node, it leaves the rest of its component behind.
7. Congratulations on not writing `using namespace std;`.
8. Avoid `std::endl` unless you really need the explicit `std::flush`. In which case you probably want to be explicit...
9. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`.

Your questions:

1. You cannot use a constant reference there because you are assigning to the member-pointer to non-const.
2. There is nothing like `self` in C++. Though at least there is no need to write the template-argument-list, as you can use the injected class-name.
   As an example:

   ```
   void merge(union_find &uf) // removed <T> from union_find
   ```
3. Yes, you made the right choices between references and pointers. You just missed a place for using a reference instead of a copy.